# dimple.js: order y-Axis not alphabetically, but by order of appearance in data set

Tags: javascript, charts, dimple.js

I'm drawing a vertically [grouped pie chart](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=pie_vertical_grouped)  in dimple.js from my data set. The chart looks similar as the one from the example link, just that my x-Axis consists of dates and the y-Axis of names of people, e.g. (imagine the `x`'s to be the pie charts):

```
- luca         x                           
- denis                                    x
- adriano                    x             x
           session1      session2      session3
```

My problem now is that I don't want the y-Axis to order the labels alphabetically, but by the fact in which session they appeared first. So, basically I want this:

```
    - denis                                     x                           
    - adriano                    x              x
    - luca         x                        
               session1      session2       session3
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried to add a `GroupOrderRule`for the y-Axis like this:

`yAxis = yAxis.addGroupOrderRule(["luca", "adriano", "denis"]);`

But the y-Axis still has the alphabetical ordering.

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the order rules which mean they aren't working for arrays right now (what you put should have worked).  You can try a workaround, adding an order field to your data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    data[i].order = i;
}

... Initialise and configure chart ...

yAxis.addGroupOrderRule("order");
```

Add a second parameter set to true if you want them in the opposite order.